# Elementary proof of Bruhat decomposition for $\mathrm{GL}_{n}$.

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G = \mathrm{GL}_{n}(k)$ for some field $k$. We have $G = \coprod_{w\in W}BwB$, where $B \leq G$ is a Borel subgroup (group of upper triangular matrices) and $W$ is a set of permutation matrices (or more generally, Weyl group of $G$).

I'm trying to prove this myself, without using any hard theory of algebraic groups. I proved that the double cosets are disjoint in a purely combinatorial way. I proved that $Bw_{1} \cap w_{2}B = \emptyset$ for any $w_1\neq w_2$, by showing that for any $b_1, b_2\in B$, there exists $i, j$ where $(i, j)$-th entry of $b_1 w_1$ is nonzero but the same entry $w_{2}b_{2}$ is zero. However, I can't show that their union is the whole $G$. 
I saw that for general reductive groups, one can show that the union forms a subgroup of $G$ by showing that $bw_{1}b'w_{2}b'' \in Bw_{3}B$ for some $w_{3}$, and consider their dimensions. 
However, I want to find some elementary proof without using any algebraic geometry, but only uses linear algebra or some combinatorial way. 
Is there any such proof? 
I know how to prove it for $n =2$, but this method (just case by case) is hard to be applied for $n \geq 3$.

Comment: Yes, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15438/a-slick-proof-of-the-bruhat-decomposition-for-gl-nk), or in [this textbook](https://books.google.at/books?id=e_JdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=Elementary+proof+of+Bruhat+decomposition+for+GL&source=bl&ots=mHUCcmpbD1&sig=ACfU3U1fwyNTmq_Wk2aEYI5Nr9boh8bFQA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbsvOhj6PhAhWq-ioKHa-zBGcQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Elementary%20proof%20of%20Bruhat%20decomposition%20for%20GL&f=false).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks! I needed the proof something like in that textbook.